# How to get SMTP response code using Laravel 5 & Amazon SES?

Tags: laravel, smtp, amazon-ses

I've been trying to get "SMTP response code (e.g. 250, 530, etc.)" in my project using Laravel5.6 & Amazon SES, but eventually I couldn't find a way to do it.

Actually, I could get the "Message ID" which is published by SES... but how can I get RAW response code?

Here's what I've tried to get Message ID from mails sent.

1) Register "LogSentMessage" listener to "MessageSent" event, which would be fired when emails are sent.

```
protected $listen = [
    'Illuminate\Mail\Events\MessageSent' => [
        'App\Listeners\LogSentMessage',
    ],
];
```

2) Get Swift_message object in "App\Listeners\LogSentMessage" listener file

```
public function handle(MessageSent $event)
{
    dd($event->message); //I could get an object containing email data
    // $event->message->getId(); gives me the Message ID.
}
```

If anyone knows how to and let me share it, I would be really appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: checkout this Swift_Events_SendEvent Api they have a method called `setResult` and `getResult`  and laravel use the same event Class in their SES Mailer service too. try `dd($event);` and check the class in more details.  http://apigen.juzna.cz/doc/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/class-Swift_Events_SendEvent.html

Comment: @Purvesh Thank you so much for nice informations! Following your advise, I could somehow get Swift_Events_SendEvent->getResult() value. However, I really want to know if there's a way to get exact SMTP response code, like 250, 454, 530, 535... any suggestions?

Comment: My assumption is that get responses code and set response code value should be: 250 or 530

Comment: @Purvesh I hoped so, but actually Swift_Events_SendEvent -> getResult() returns one of these: 0x0001, 0x0011, 0x0010, 0x0100, 0x1000 - which means pending, spooled, success, tentative success, failure, respectively.

Answer (score 2):

**You were on the right track.**

The best/only way I found to get the MessageId is by wading through the headers of the sent message.

Inside the `handle()` function of your `App\Listeners\LogSentMessage` you'll be able to get the MessageId like so:

```
public function handle(MessageSent $event)
{
    $message_id = $event->message
        ->getHeaders()
        ->get('x-ses-message-id')
        ->getValue();
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much Linus! Sorry for late reply.
I'm afraid even with this method it remains being unable to get *raw SMTP response code*...

Comment: I don't have the code to double-check this, but what about if you `dd()` the `$event->message->getHeaders()` call?

Comment: remember to keep MAIL_MAILER=ses and not smtp. if used smtp Laravel will come up with own message id